# Is it possible to store a deferred command execution in a bash variable?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have already looked [deferred variable expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60688/how-to-defer-variable-expansion) but that does not appear to work for the problem here, unless I have misunderstood it.

**I want to create a shell variable which always evaluates to the current time in a particular format.** Here is my first attempt.

```
foo=$(date +'%H-%M-%S')
```

Unfortunately, this will run the command and assign its result to the variable `foo`. Instead, I want to be able to say `$foo` and have the command run and give me the result.

---

To give a more real use case, suppose I have a (black-box) program called `WriteOutputTo` which takes as its first argument the filename to write output to. I would like to be able to write the following on the shell.

```
./WriteOutputTo Output_$foo
```

I realize that this can be done with the following method, but it seems overly verbose and I'd like to know if its possible to use a short variable instead.

```
./WriteOutputTo Output_$(date +'%H-%M-%S')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest you can come in bash is to define foo as a function:

```
foo(){ date +'%H-%M-%S'; }
```

and then you can write

```
./WriteOutputTo Output_$(foo)
```

Other shells have mechanisms to accomplish this. For example, in `ksh` you could define the "get" *discipline function* for `foo`:

```
foo.get() { .sh.value=$(date +'%H-%M-%S'); }
```

after which any use of `$foo` will return the result of running the data command.

Comment: Thanks for the note about the `ksh` feature. Are you sure there's no way to do this in `bash`?

Comment: @merlin2011: Yes, I'm sure there is no way to do it in bash. Of course, you could modify bash. Bash is open source and moreover has a funcctional if rather badly documented loadable module feature, which would probably allow implementation of this feature.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can simply use a bash function:

```
foo() {
    date +'%H-%M-%S'
}

$ foo
22-48-50
$ foo
22-48-52
```

Comment: This does not satisfy the given use case since bash will not recognize `Output_foo` as a concatenation of the literal string `Output_` and the result of the function call.

Comment: It's a very small step to put the output into `Output_$(foo)`. The question was more about a dynamic method of getting time.

Comment: Actually, the question is about saving keystrokes. I already have a dynamic method of getting time. :)

Comment: I just noticed you are the original asker. Excuse me for arguing about the intent of your question :). You do say you want `Output_$(foo)` to be dynamic, so I think you have your answer from both answers posted?

Comment: Yes it is. However, I'm going to leave the question unaccepted a little bit longer to see if someone comes up with a way of killing the `()`  to go all the way down to `$foo`. Ultimately I would want `$T` and `$(T)` is 50% more keystrokes.

Comment: If you are sooooo keen to save keystrokes, you can save one keystroke by using `\`T\`` instead of `$(T)` :D